# Sitecore Site not loading after Sitecore 9.1 installation: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: installation

I installed Sitecore 9.1 and no issues showed during installation, but when I try to load the local site, the browser can't connect to it. Chrome shows the error: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

I don't know what will be causing this issue.

Note: I have another Sitecore 10.2 instance installed and this works absolutely fine.

Comment: Can you check you have correct binding added in IIs and also the host name resolves to your local machine? Also, please review logs in add_data/logs and provide any main exceptions shown

Comment: make sure the valid url its provided in host entry

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for this error, such as `incorrect configuration` settings, `network` issues, or `firewall` settings.

You can try checking your firewall settings, resetting your network settings, or using a `different browser`.

Could you please check and eliminate you are none of the cases [How to Fix the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Error in Chrome: 7 Quick Ways](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-err-connection-reset-error#:%7E:text=The%20ERR_CONNECTION_RESET%20error%20means%20that,send%20data%20to%20your%20browser.)?

If none of above works for you, suggest you can process with the following:

1. Check the `Sitecore logs` of the not running instance to confirm if it's working ok or with any `exception/errors`. Look for any error messages or exceptions that may be related to the issue.
2. `Restart the IIS app pool` to verify if it's a web server issue. Sometimes, the issue may be related to the web server rather than the Sitecore instance itself.
3. If the issue persists, you could try `reinstalling` the Sitecore instance with a `clean instance`.

If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to connect with me.